# How To Destroy one enemy without affecting other enemies of the same type?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a problem, I have a universal enemy script, which I use on all enemies, but as in the script when an enemy dies it is set to deactivate the current script and because of that the first enemy goes perfectly to kill him, but when I arrive at the second I can't attack him because he says the script is disabled and he can't access it, how can I do when I kill an enemy not to affect the main script of all enemies?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    #region Public Variables

    public int maxHealth = 100; //Enemy max health;
    public int currentHealth; // Enemy current health;

    public Transform leftLimit; //Left limit for patrolling;
    public Transform rightLimit; //Right limit for patrolling;
    
    [HideInInspector] public Transform target; //Find the Player;


    [HideInInspector] public GameObject heartLeftOne, heartLeftTwo, heartMiddle, heartRightTwo, heartRightOne; //Enemy hearts;
    public GameObject damageText; //Damage Text Popup;
    public GameObject goldPrefab; //Gold Prefab;
    public GameObject enemyHearts; //All enemy Hearts stored in a Empty gameobject for a much easy way to deactivate them;
    public GameObject hitBox; //Where we check if player entered in attackRange for enemy;
    public GameObject hotZone; //Hotzone is where enemy will follow the player;
    public GameObject triggerArea; //TriggerArea detect if player entered in Range of Enemy AI;

    public bool cooling; //Check if Enemy is cooling after attack
    public bool attackMode; //Check when enemy is in Attack mode or not;
    public bool facingRight; //If FacingRight is true or false;
    public bool playerInRange; //If Player is in Range set the bool true;
    
    [HideInInspector] public bool inRange; //Check if Player is in TriggerArea Range;

    public float attackDistance; //Minimum distance for attack
    public float moveSpeed; //Speed of enemy;
    public float timer; //Timer for cooldown between attacks
    
    #endregion

    #region Private Variables
    
    private Animator anim; //Animator;
    
    private float distance; //Store the distance b/w enemy and player
    private float intTimer; // Cooldown b/w enemy attack;
    private float textPositionX = 0.5f; //Position X for Damage Text;
    private float textPositionY = 1.5f; //Position Y for Damage Text;
    private float goldPositionY = 0.5f; //Gold Positon Y when Enemy Die;
    private float localScaleX = 0.5f; //Scale X for Gold Prefab;
    private float localScaleY = 0.5f; //Scale Y for Gold Prefab;

    private Experience_System experience; //Reference to Leveling system;
    private Player_Health player; //Reference for Player Health;
    
    #endregion

    //Function Awake;
    public void Awake()
    {
        //Check what limit is closer for patrolling;
        SelectTarget();

        intTimer = timer; //Store the inital value of timer
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>(); //Animator;
    }

    //Start Function;
    public void Start ()
    {
        //Start health for enemy;
        currentHealth = maxHealth;

        //Hearts for enemy;
        heartRightOne.SetActive(true);
        heartRightTwo.SetActive(true);
        heartMiddle.SetActive(true);
        heartRightTwo.SetActive(true);
        heartLeftOne.SetActive(true);

        //Find The GameObject and Take the Scripts Function;
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Player_Health>();
        experience = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Experience").GetComponent<Experience_System>();
    }
    
    //Update Function;
    public void Update()
    {
        if (!attackMode)
        {
            Move();
        }

        if (!InsideOfLimits() && !inRange)
        {
            SelectTarget();
        }

        if (inRange)
        {
            EnemyLogic();
        }
    }

    public void EnemyLogic()
    {
        distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.position);

        if (distance > attackDistance)
        {
            StopAttack();
        }
       
        else if (attackDistance >= distance && cooling == false)
        {
            Attack();
        }

        if (cooling)
        {
            Cooldown();
            anim.SetBool("Attack", false);
        }
    }

    public void Move()
    {
        anim.SetBool("Walk", true);

        Vector2 targetPosition = new Vector2(target.position.x, transform.position.y);

        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    public void Attack()
    {
        timer = intTimer; //Reset Timer when Player enter Attack Range
        attackMode = true; //To check if Enemy can still attack or not

        anim.SetBool("Walk", false);
        anim.SetBool("Attack", true);
    }

    public void Cooldown()
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer <= 0 && cooling && attackMode)
        {
            cooling = false;
            timer = intTimer;
        }
    }

    public void StopAttack()
    {
        cooling = false;
        attackMode = false;
        anim.SetBool("Attack", false);
    }

    public void TriggerCooling()
    {
        cooling = true;
    }

    //Enemy Take Damage;
    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        currentHealth -= damage;
        anim.SetTrigger("TakeHit");

        if (currentHealth == 80)
        {
            heartRightOne.SetActive(false);
        }

        else if (currentHealth == 60)
        {
            heartRightOne.SetActive(false);
            heartRightTwo.SetActive(false);
        }

        else if (currentHealth == 40)
        {
            heartRightOne.SetActive(false);
            heartRightTwo.SetActive(false);
            heartMiddle.SetActive(false);
        }

        else if (currentHealth == 20)
        {
            heartRightOne.SetActive(false);
            heartRightTwo.SetActive(false);
            heartMiddle.SetActive(false);
            heartLeftTwo.SetActive(false);
        }

        else if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            Die();

            heartRightOne.SetActive(false);
            heartRightTwo.SetActive(false);
            heartMiddle.SetActive(false);
            heartLeftTwo.SetActive(false);
            heartLeftOne.SetActive(false);
        }

        //Check if the enemy is facingRight or not to display the damage text popup;
        if (facingRight == true)
        {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(damageText, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            go.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = damage.ToString();
            go.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
            go.transform.localPosition += new Vector3(Random.Range(-textPositionX, textPositionX), Random.Range(+textPositionY, 2), Random.Range(0, 0));
        }
        
        else if (!facingRight)
        {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(damageText, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            go.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = damage.ToString();
            go.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
            go.transform.localPosition += new Vector3(Random.Range(-textPositionX, textPositionX), Random.Range(+textPositionY, 2), Random.Range(0, 0));
        }
    }

    //Die Funtction
    public void Die()
    {
        //Set The Animation For Dead and Stop all other functions / animations of the enemy;  
        anim.SetBool("Dead", true);
        anim.SetBool("Attack", false);
        anim.SetBool("Walk", false);

        attackMode = false;
        inRange = false;
        cooling = false;

        //Instantiate a Gold Prefab;
        GameObject gold = Instantiate(goldPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

        gold.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
        gold.transform.localPosition = new Vector2(0, goldPositionY);
        gold.transform.localScale = new Vector2(localScaleX, localScaleY);

        //Set Player +25 Experience;
        experience.IncraeseExp(25);

        //Deactivate The Enemy Collider;
        GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false;

        //Destroy The Enemy AI;
        Destroy(hotZone);
        Destroy(triggerArea);
        Destroy(hitBox);
        Destroy(enemyHearts);
    }

    //Check if enemy is inside of patrolling limits;
    public bool InsideOfLimits()
    {
        return transform.position.x > leftLimit.position.x && transform.position.x < rightLimit.position.x;
    }

    //Function For Patrolling state;
    public void SelectTarget()
    {
        float distanceToLeft = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, leftLimit.position);
        float distanceToRight = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, rightLimit.position);

        if (distanceToLeft > distanceToRight)
        {
            target = leftLimit;
        }
        
        else if (distanceToLeft < distanceToRight)
        {
            target = rightLimit;
        }

        Flip();
    }

    //Function for flip the enemy;
    public void Flip()
    {
        Vector3 rotation = transform.eulerAngles;
        
        if (transform.position.x < target.position.x)
        {
            rotation.y = 180;
            facingRight = true;
        }
        
        else
        {
            rotation.y = 0;
            facingRight = false;
        }

        transform.eulerAngles = rotation;
    }

    //If Player enter the trgger where enemy can attack set bool to true;
    public void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag.Equals("Player"))
        {
            playerInRange = true;
        }
    }

    //If Player leave the trigger where enemy can attack set bool back to false;
    public void OnTriggerExit2D (Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag.Equals("Player"))
        {
            playerInRange = false;
        }
    }

    // Player will take damage from enemy if the player is in Range of enemy for attack;
    public void PlayerTakeDamage ()
    {
        if (playerInRange == true)
        {
            player.TakeDamage();
        }

        else if (playerInRange == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("Player not in Range!");
        }
    }
}
```

Because the script is done this way, when I go to attack the second enemy, I can't kill him anymore If help I can make a video to show the entire script bcs its a big one and to show exactly the problem

Comment: Can you include the declaration of  your class-level variables (like `currentHealth`, `heartRightOne`, etc.) in your question? I suspect that your mistake might be there.

Comment: You are probably still trying to affect your killed enemy, you are not affecting your current enemy. Please put some logs into your code to see which enemy you are trying to hurt.

Comment: @Philipp  I editet the post and put all the enemy script

Comment: @ÇağatayIŞIK Yes, Now I Run another test, and Yea, after I kill first enemy and go to the second one, my character still trying to affect the first enemy which is already dead

Comment: OK, you did not declare your variables as `static` and you don't seem to `Find` any sub-objects at runtime. That leaves the question how you set up things in the editor. Are all those other objects you are referencing children of your prefab? **Is** your enemy a prefab?

Comment: @Philipp Look, I made here a video with the everything i use on enemy and player, and a video with play mode to see what errors i got in console, just wait a little bit for youtube to process the video to full HD https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RDVxTcSXvA&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @ÇağatayIŞIK I tried already your method, but still doesn't working, look here is a video with the entire system https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RDVxTcSXvA&feature=youtu.be    If you can understand better, but I guess my problem is in Void DIE () in Enemy script, because if enemy is <= 0 health I Destroy The Hitbox, triggerZone, and HotZone and disable the current enemy script, and probably because I disable and destroy these things when I go to the second enemy the player trying to kill it but hotzone, triggerArea, hitbox and the script doesn't exist anymore, but check the video please

Comment: The video shows a bunch of `MissingReferenceException` errors. When you double-click on one of those then it should lead you to the line in your sourcecode where that error occurs. Can you show us which line that is?

Comment: Agreed with @Philipp, could you show us the error line and also log that line to see what is null.

Comment: @ÇağatayIŞIK So, the null reference comes from enemy hearts, i deactivate enemy hearts, and if you can see I kill first enemy, I go to the second one, but when i hit second one, my player still hitting the dead body and i guess the problem is on this line //Destroy 
//Destroy The Enemy AI;
        Destroy(hotZone);
        Destroy(triggerArea);
        Destroy(hitBox);

        //Deactivate the current enemy script;
        this.enabled = false;  here i disable the script from enemy         https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBkQmh7yuRk

Comment: But you are not even referencing `enemyHearts` in the code you posted, except for the line where you Destroy them. Have you considered that the problem might not actually be the enemy but rather the player script?

Comment: @Philipp But what can be in player script? Probably is from player_hitbox where i check if enemy is in hitbox collider?

Comment: @Kymbers Unrelated to your question but still wanting to tell you `experience.IncraeseExp(25);` the function has a spelling mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually in the `Player_Combat.cs` script which isn't in the question and only visible shortly in [the linked video at 3:20](https://youtu.be/_RDVxTcSXvA?t=200).

It has a variable `private Enemy enemy` which it obtains once in `Start` and then never changes. That makes the player unable to interact with any other enemy except the one it found at the beginning of the game.

Instead of having the concept of a "current enemy", I would recommend to rather check what's in front of the player the moment when they attack, see if any of those objects are still living enemies, and then damage them.

One method you can use to detect colliders which overlap a given area is [`Physics2D.OverlapAreaAll`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapAreaAll.html) (or perhaps another of the Overlap* methods of class [`Physics2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D)). This method returns an array of all colliders which overlap a rectangular area. But keep in mind that not all of these colliders might be enemies, and not all of these enemies might still be alive.

Untested code:

```
Collider[] detectedColliders = Physics2D.OverlapAreaAll(/* A box in front of the current player position*/);
foreach (Collider detectedCollider in detectedColliders) {
    Enemy detectedEnemy = detectedCollider.GetComponent<Enemy>();
    if(detectedEnemy != null && detectedEnemy.currentHealth > 0) { 
          detectedEnemy.TakeDamage(damage);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want the player to be able to engage more than one enemy at a time and keep the concept of a single "current enemy", then you need to implement the code for changing that variable to a different enemy when appropriate and also need to handle the case that there might be times when there isn't any enemy at all in the game.

Comment: Omg, it worked, now is working fine, everything working, thank you a lot!!! And thanks to everyone who tried to help me!!!

Comment: P.S: I spent 5 days to figure out why this attack system don't work, thank you again all!!!